# A rather peculiar problem: XeLaTeX, hyperref and lots of warnings

Tags: xetex, hyperref

When I compile my document using XeLaTeX I get the following error:

```
** WARNING ** Can't begin an annotation when one is pending.
** WARNING ** Interpreting special command bann (pdf:) failed.
** WARNING ** >> at page="6" position="(232.638, 77.032)" (in PDF)
** WARNING ** >> xxx "pdf:bann<</Type/Annot/Subtype/Link/Border[0 0 0]/C[0 1 0]/A<..."
** WARNING ** >> Reading special command stopped around >><</Type/Annot/Subtype/Link/Border[0 0 0]/C[0 1 0]/A<</S/GoTo...<< 
** WARNING ** Tried to end an annotation without starting one! 
** WARNING ** Interpreting special command eann (pdf:) failed. 
** WARNING ** >> at page="7" position="(94.9061, 708.045)" (in PDF) 
** WARNING ** >> xxx "pdf:eann"
```

Any thoughts of why I get this error?

Update 1: There seems to be a "collision" between XeLaTeX and hyperref. The problem is solved when you use pdflatex, but how about xelatex? Is there any hope?

Update 2: I had a `\section{smth}` that was empty for I will prepare it later, something like an intro in the main paper, but I just wanted to have it there for future reference. Now, I am doing some work on what follows. It seems that XeLaTeX and hyperref do not like this kind of behaviour though. Now, when you start writing in this section the problem disappears. However, I do not know if this one counts as a an answer to the problem. I leave that to the mods to decide.

Update3: (I am sorry if I make you tired). Now, I think, I understand the problem. It is a combination of Update 2 and half-finished paragraphs. That is in a previous section(just before what I mention in Update 2) there is another one that has two paragraphs. The first one is finished, but the second is not. Actually it only has a small sentence. It seems that after you use `par` a certain number of characters must be filled (I do not know the exact number, but I tried with different lengths and it works after a specific threshold). I also tried with pdflatex, but it works fine with it.

Comment: Without a MWE, which may be difficult to create, you're probably going to have to answer your own question.

Comment: @jon I think so :(                                               I need to find out what creates this conflict.

Comment: Really weird! In the paragraph that the problem is found, if I erase/delete words arbitrarily, more than 4, the warning disappears. I have never seen that before. This makes me think that there is something in the paragraph that I cannot see ...

Comment: It's very hard without a MWE. Just shooting at the air here, but check this out: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/comp.text.tex/fR9Y_e6Zo5E. Disable hyperref and check if the problem is gone.

Comment: @NIco But I need to have hyperref! It is not the first time that I use this format. What are the nested links? They say it may due to them.

Comment: @PantelisKazakis Try to see if that is causing the problem first, then you may deal with it.

Comment: @Nico, hyperref is the problem. What should I do?

Comment: So, it is a problem of the compiling engine. If you use pdflatex, then the warnings are no more. However, this may not be an ideal solution for someone who want to use XeLaTeX.

Comment: I don't know, but now that you have narrowed the problem, try to make a MWE with the error so someone can help you. Without a MWE is really hard.

Comment: Re the second update.  Why not just put something like `\null` or `~` or even `\phantom{TODO}` in the empty section?  (However, this may deserve to be brought to the attention of the `hyperref` and/or `XeTeX` developers ... but without the MWE ...)

Comment: @Nico Both of your suggestions work fine. I think you are right. This point must be seen better from the developers of hyperref I suppose.

Comment: I suspect links broken across pages, e.g. in a footnote, with links in header/footer or somethink like this. I do not know a driver that *fully* supports page breaks in links. I do not think, an "empty" section is related to the problem. Rather the page breaking changes by adding stuff moving the links to safer locations.

Comment: If you do `\usepackage[preserveurlmacro]{breakurl}` you will disable all line breaks (and therefore page breaks) in URLs.  That will likely result in some overfull hboxes from long URLs, and you can judiciously replace the `\url` macro with `\burl` to fix them.  Hopefully that will fix the problem, but if you're still left choosing between an overfull hbox or a broken hyperref across a page break, then your only option is to reword or tinker with the layout.  Don't do that until the end, though!  I once wasted hours fixing similar problems, only to realise my abstract still read `\lipsum`!

Comment: I just had exactly this error.